# I would like to import a csv with employees and create a hierarchy of the data

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to create a powershell script that will import a csv that has employees in the following format.

```
ID,FirstName, LastName, Managers ID
1, John, Doe, 0 (is the top of hierarchy)
2, Jane, Doe, 1
45, Josh, Davis, 1
33, Steve, Clark, 2
```

my problem is, as the employees are in the csv they are not in order of the hierarchy. Is there a way to organize these people and export it to another csv file?

Comment: you are not showing any code for how you attempted to solve the problem, and your sample data is way too small to understand how it should look with multiple managers and employees, and employees who are managers under another manager, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by @Kory Gill, you missing some constrains for a proper definition of your request (and they do not show from your example either), like:

- **The `Id` and `ManagerId` column do not have to be in order**
  (or is a manager higher in the hierarchy always listed first?)
- **There is no relation between `ManagerId` and the hierarchy level**
  (or has a manager higher in the hierarchy always a lower `ManagerId`?)
- **The depth of the hierarchy is undefined (unlimited)**
  (I presume that the number of manager levels could always grow after a reorganization)

Presuming that the above constrains apply, the question gets more complex but also more challenging. To show this, I have set the `Id` of the the top manager `John Doe` to `11` and sorted the list accordingly, leaving the original hierarchy intact:

```
$Employees = ConvertFrom-Csv 'ID, FirstName, LastName, ManagerId
2, Jane, Doe, 11
11, John, Doe, 0 
45, Josh, Davis, 11
33, Steve, Clark, 2'
```

Which this requirements, you might want to create a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) function to figure out the manager of the manager (of the manager ... etc). Below is an example how you might tackel this:

```
Function Add-ManagerLevel([Object[]]$Employees) {

    Function Get-Level($ManagerId, [Int]$Level = 0) {               # 0 is the top of hierarchy
        $Manager = $Employees | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $ManagerId}
        If (!$Manager) {$Level} Else {Get-Level $Manager.ManagerId ($Level + 1)}
    }

    $Employees | ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Add-Member "Level" (Get-Level $_.ManagerId) -PassThru
    }
}
```

note that the `Get-Level` help function calls itself to find out if a manager has a higher manager.
This will give the following output:

```
Add-ManagerLevel $Employees | Format-Table

ID FirstName LastName ManagerId Level
-- --------- -------- --------- -----
2  Jane      Doe      11            1
11 John      Doe      0             0
45 Josh      Davis    11            1
33 Steve     Clark    2             2
```

Which this result you can sort your list on hierarchy level, e.g.:

```
Add-ManagerLevel $Employees | Sort-Object Level | Format-Table
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kory Gill's comment.
However, making some assumptions. Do you mean something like this?

```
Clear-Host
(Import-Csv -Path 'E:\Temp\Employees.csv' | 
Select-Object -Property 'Managers ID', ID, FirstName, LastName | 
Group-Object -Property 'Managers ID' | 
Sort-Object -Property  'Managers ID',ID) | 
ForEach{
    "Processing GroupManagersID $($PSItem.Name)`t" + ('*')*20 
    ForEach ($Staff in $PSItem)
    {
        $Staff.Group | 
        Select-Object -Property ID, FirstName, LastName 
    }
    "`n"
}


# Results

Processing GroupManagersID 0    ********************

ID FirstName LastName
-- --------- --------
1  John      Doe     


Processing GroupManagersID 1    ********************
2  Jane      Doe     
45 Josh      Davis   


Processing GroupManagersID 2    ********************
33 Steve     Clark
```